# WPF application cleanup on exit

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM app.
It has a View and relevant ViewModel.
ViewModel has an ObservableCollection of SerialPorts. Closing each port takes few seconds.
Now I close my app just hitting the 'X' button - and if I use app.OnExit - my ViewModel is already disposed. When debugging - this sometimes gives me all sorts of compiler's strange behaviors, I give up trying to understand/fix them all.

On app's close/exit - how can I call some method in my ViewModel, to close all ports (which can take minutes), and do some other cleanup?

Comment: what do you mean, your viewmodel is diposed? who disposed it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any given Window, you can use the [Window.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event.